# How to change CSS classes and style for nav tabs after bslib nav_insert?

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, bslib

Currently for the `bslib` package, a `nav_insert()` into a `page_navbar` does not pass along the same CSS classes as it does for a regular tab-pane, as noted in this [issue posted to the](https://github.com/rstudio/bslib/issues/952) `bslib` Github repo.

The reprex provided by the OP is the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_navbar(
  id = 'nav',
  nav_panel('Page 1',
            card("Content 1")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  nav_insert(id = "nav",
             nav = nav_panel('Page 2',
                             card("Content 2")))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The newly inserted tab "Page 2" does not have the same css classes as the "Page 1" tab, namely `html-fill-item html-fill-container bslib-gap-spacing`.

Is there a way, perhaps, to add those classes after the insert?  I tried using `runjs($('[data-value=Page 1]').addClass('html-fill-item'))` (and several iterations of it) in the server but that did not work.

A [very trivial JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/76tkcyr2/) shows the idea of the basic working syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `class` and `style` explicitly to `nav_panel`.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_navbar(
    id = 'nav',
    nav_panel('Page 1',
              card("Content 1")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    nav_insert(id = "nav",
               nav = nav_panel('Page 2',
                               class = "html-fill-item html-fill-container bslib-gap-spacing",
                               style = "--bslib-navbar-margin:0;",
                               card("Content 2")))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```